# SIlverlight and Jetty

Tags: silverlight, jetty, xap

Can anyone tell me if org.mortbay.jetty.Server "Jetty" can serve XAP (Silverlight) files?

I have an RCP Eclipse Plugin application with embedded Jetty and want to add Silverlight to the mix.

Answer (score 1):

XAPs require no special handling (they are just downloaded as files by Silverlight) so you just need to add the XAP as a new MIME type to your Jetty web.xml file

http://account.pacip.com/jetty/doc/MimeTypes.html